# Apagar seleção de um List

Tags: java, awt

Na minha classe java criei um formulario e nele criei um botão que limpa todos os campos.

Porém não estou conseguindo fazer com que apague a seleção de um `list` que tenho no formulario, ele apaga os *textfield* e *radios butto*n mas não o list.

Obs: não estou usando JList e sim List. Já tentei assim ´NomeCurso.clearSelection();` mas o código fica vermelho incorreto e não deseleciona o item.

```
NomeCurso = new List(5, false);
Nome Curso.setSize(200, 170);
NomeCurso.setLocation(480, 145);
NomeCurso.addItem("Adm");
NomeCurso.addItem("Biomedicina");
NomeCurso.addItem("Ciencia da computacao");
NomeCurso.addItem("Farmacia");
NomeCurso.addItem("Direito");
NomeCurso.addItem("Educação física");

...

getContentPane().add(NomeCurso);
```

Comment: NomeCurso.getListModel().removerAllElements(); não funcionaria?

Comment: Coloca o pacote do list também pra ter mais material pra fazer um exemplo aqui

Comment: Adicione um **[mcve]** do seu código para que seja possivel analisar o problema.

Comment: Nao o getListModel ficou vermelho

Comment: NomeCurso.removeAll();
Talvez você tenha que dar um repaint() depois também

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para o pacote `java.awt.List`, de acordo com o [`Javadoc`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/List.html), para limpar a seleção você deve utilizar o método `deselect(int index)`. O índice pode ser dado pelo método `getSelectedIndex()` como no exemplo:

```
NomeCurso.deselect(NomeCurso.getSelectedIndex());
```

A propósito, se você está usando `Swing` o ideal é utilizar o [`JList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html).

> [`List.deselect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/List.html#deselect(int))
>
> Deselects the item at the specified index.

Em tradução livre:

> Deseleciona o item especificado no índice.

---

> [`List.getSelectedItem`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/List.html#getSelectedItem())
>
> Gets the selected item on this scrolling list.

Em tradução livre:

> Obtém o item selecionado na lista de rolagem.

Comment: Nao ele apagou todos os elementos deixando a caixinha do List em branco, mas eu queria só q ele deselecionasse o item selecionado

Comment: Ah tah, tenta então NomeCurso.deselect(NomeCurso.getSelectedIndex());

Comment: /o\ deu certo!!!!  vlw

Comment: Vou alterar a resposta então para bater com a pergunta